# Indentation of "References" in the table of contents of RevTex

Tags: bibliographies, revtex, bibliographystyle

I use revtex as

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,nofootinbib,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,11pt,longbibliography,floatfix]{revtex4-2}
```

and inside the text, at the beginning, `\tableofcontents` and, at the end `\bibliography{filename}`

The toc looks like this

1. Intro
2. Second title

   References

How can I get this without the indentation before "References"? The following is desired:

1. Intro
2. Second title
3. Last title

References

Thank you for any hint!

```
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

% USE OF THIS FILE:
%
% latex Test; latex Test; latex Test; bibtex Test; latex Test; latex Test; latex Test; dvips Test; ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dFastWebView=true  Test.ps Test.pdf 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[onecolumn,nofootinbib,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,11pt,longbibliography,floatfix]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\section{Sectiontitle}   

\noindent Text \cite{einstein1905elektrodynamik}.

\bibliography{Test} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although the hint to the document class you use is already helpful, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that also shows which packages you use.

Comment: Added such a file.

Answer (score 0):

```latex
\documentclass[onecolumn,nofootinbib,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,11pt,longbibliography,floatfix]{revtex4-2}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\hskip-1em References}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Sectiontitle}

\noindent Text \cite{einstein1905elektrodynamik}.

\bibliography{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great - thank you!

Comment: But it yields an error with hyperref, I just found out. Still - thank you!

Comment: @KlausK If you use `hyperref` package, you can `\renewcommand{\refname}{\texorpdfstring{\hskip-1em References}{References}}` to avoid warning.

Comment: Thank you - once more.